# Deploying .vbhtml on Local IIS Installation

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005, iis, razor, webmatrix

I've come into a company that has been using asp.net for some web applications stored on our local servers. There's no current programmer, so I've used what knowledge I have to build a new feature using MebMatrix Razor VB.NET pages and our current SQL Server database. I have to migrate the project over to a local server running IIS to deploy it.

I don't want to use the WebMatrix Web Deploy feature or anything, I'd rather just move the files over manually and have them run. I assume that IIS just needs to be configured to process .vbhtml file extensions. My understanding is that you don't have to build your solution with this method, as you do with ASP. Does anybody know how to do this, or where I might find a good tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the directory for your website from the 'My Web Sites' folder in Documents. Paste it into the 'inetpub' directory on the server.

Now open IIS Manager, on the left hand side in the connections pane, right click on 'Sites' and 'Add Web Site'. Choose a name, select the default AppPool, browser to the 'inetpub' directory and select your site's folder, set a port that doesn't conflict with any other sites running, and click OK.

On the right hand pane, click browse, you should be able to see your new website.